# Labels on plot pie so close

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I`m run this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
from matplotlib import rc
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv",";")
data["count"].plot(kind='pie',subplots=True,colors=['#0099FF','#0089e5','#007acc','#006bb2','#005b99'],labels=data["name"],autopct='%.2f')
plt.axis('equal')
```

And get pie plot, all good, but lables on plot so close.
How I can fix it?
[My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OYwG.png) 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options might be to `explode` the plot and/or move the percent labels by `pctdistance`. (For full details see [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie).)

`pctdistance` sets the distance of the percentage labels as a fraction of the radius. So `1.1` will place the labels just outside the pie. `0.9` will place them just inside.

For example:

```
data["count"].plot(kind='pie',subplots=True,colors=['#0099FF','#0089e5','#007acc','#006bb2','#005b99'],labels=data["name"],
    autopct='%.2f', pctdistance=0.9,
    explode=len(data["count"])*[0.2])
```

Comment: If use your example: http://i.imgur.com/spsFY4r.png
If edit value: http://i.imgur.com/q5CVpk4.png the distance between the pieces too large.

Comment: Possible to make this? (only line to labels): http://i.imgur.com/7pVr0qO.png (Excel)

Comment: Not sure about the lines to labels, but you can try different label placements, without exploding, such as `pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=1.2`.

Comment: It work with labeldistance=1.7, but distance labels to pieces so far.